so while using playwright's "new_context" and evaluating some js it says Page.evaluate: SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
why does it happen? it works if used with selenium or without new_context option.
the code ->
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import asyncio, json

async def get_hsw(req):
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = await browser.new_context(
            user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
            viewport={"width": 1920, "height": 1080},
            device_scale_factor=2,
            geolocation={'latitude': 37.7749, 'longitude': -122.4194},
            java_script_enabled=True,
            color_scheme="dark",
            accept_downloads=True,
            offline=False,
            bypass_csp=True
        )

        try:
            with open('hsw.js', 'r') as f:
                data = f.read()

            page = await context.new_page()
            await page.goto("http://localhost:80")
            await page.wait_for_load_state("domcontentloaded")

            hsw = await page.evaluate(f'{json.dumps(data)}; return hsw("{req}")')
            print(hsw)
            return hsw
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred: {e}")

        finally:
            await context.close()
            await browser.close()

the hsw.js is more than 3k lines of code and is formatted nicely
i was expecting it to return the encrypted key generated using the 'req' data.

It may help to print the string with which you call page.evaluate (before calling it, of course).

await page.wait_for_load_state("domcontentloaded") is unnecessary. goto already waits for load. hsw = await page.evaluate(f'{json.dumps(data)}; return hsw("{req}")') looks incorrect, but what is hsw.js and what are you trying to achieve on the page? What is running at http://localhost:80? Please share a runnable [mcve] to get help.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

ik these i have tried everything. it works with selenium but not with playwright

Nevermind fixed it myself lmao. Just had to remove the "return"

page.evaluate expects JavaScript code and the error is a JavaScript error. It happens because of the return, as you determined, for much the same reason that it would in Python: return only works inside a function (i.e., a context that one could actually return from).
